# bundle install libv8 keeps loading for ages

Tags: ruby, rubygems

So I'm trying to install `libv8 (3.11.8.17)` that is a dependency of `therubyracer` on Mac OS Mountain Lion. However it keeps loading for ages.... Saying:

`Installing libv8 (3.11.8.17) with native extensions`

**Didn't work:**

- uninstalling and installing libv8
- brew install v8 and then installing libv8
- downgrading therubyracer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I was running ruby-1.8.7

And the solution: [How do I install the libv8 ruby gem on a fresh Mountain Lion install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731600/how-do-i-install-the-libv8-ruby-gem-on-a-fresh-mountain-lion-install)