# Installing libv8 gem on OS X 10.9+

Tags: rubygems, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite, libv8

I'm trying to install libv8 3.16.14.3 but getting an error on OSX Mavericks using latest stable rvm and ruby-1.9.3-p125.

This is the output of running the command 'gem install libv8':

```
~/src(branch:master) » gem install libv8
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Using compiler: g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
libtool: unrecognized option `-static'
libtool: Try `libtool --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/libpreparser_lib.a] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
  from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
  from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
  build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                -S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/conversions.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/diy-fp.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fast-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fixed-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/once.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparse-data.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser-api.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/scanner.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/strtod.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/token.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/unicode.o
  CXX(target) /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/utils.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/libpreparser_lib.a


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@proj-rails3-ruby19/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Be aware that Rails projects [do not need therubyracer](https://kmitov.com/posts/we-dont-need-therubyracer-and-the-libv8-error-for-compiling-native-extensions/) just to pre-compile assets as long as [execjs](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) can find NodeJS in your path.

Answer (score 478, accepted):

This is due to the fact that OS X 10.9+ is using version 4.8 of GCC. This is not supported officially in older versions of libv8 as mentioned in the pull request (https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/pull/95). Please try bumping up the version of libv8 in your Gemfile (or) a `bundle update` should suffice.

From the libv8 [README](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8#bring-your-own-compiler)

**Bring your own V8**

Because libv8 is the interface for the V8 engine used by therubyracer, you may need to use libv8, even if you have V8 installed already. If you wish to use your own V8 installation, rather than have it built for you, use the --with-system-v8 option.

Using RubyGems:

> gem install libv8 [-v YOUR_VERSION] -- --with-system-v8

Using Bundler (in your Gemfile):

> bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8

Please note that if you intend to run your own V8, you must install both V8 and its headers (found in libv8-dev for Debian distros).

**Bring your own compiler**

You can specify a compiler of your choice by either setting the CXX environment variable before compilation, or by adding the --with-cxx= option to the bundle configuration:

> bundle config build.libv8 --with-cxx=clang++

Edit:

If this issue is brought on by `therubyracer`, try the following as suggested by [rider_on_rails](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197091/rider-on-rails) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536893/installing-libv8-and-therubyracer-gems-on-mavericks-with-system-v8-installation):

> gem uninstall libv8
>
> gem install therubyracer -v YOUR_RUBY_RACER_VERSION
>
> gem install libv8 -v YOUR_VERSION -- --with-system-v8

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the version of libv8 in the project I'm working on. I'll be downgrading to OSX 10.8 for now!

Comment: `--with-system-v8` FTW!

Comment: Thanks!

    `bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8`

helps!

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but `YOUR_VERSION` of what?

Comment: YOUR_VERSION refers to libv8 version as specified in the Gemfile or the locked version in the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: `bundle update` bailed me out of the realm of numbness and apple-upgrade-inflicted-miseries

Comment: This worked, but I was also required to bump the version in Gemfile to match `YOUR_VERSION`.

Comment: In case someone gets the following problem with `therubyracer` gem after solving this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536893/installing-libv8-and-therubyracer-gems-on-mavericks-with-system-v8-installation

Comment: This one helped me `bundle config build.libv8 --with-cxx=clang++`.

Comment: I have the same issue. Finally I found a very tricky way to fix it.
You need to find a person who installed it correctly and copy the missing file to your computer in correct path.

Comment: Seems like I was able to handle therubyracer with `bundle` after running `bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8`

Answer (score 224):

You can actually install that version on Mavericks:

```
gem install libv8 -v 3.11.8.17 -- --with-system-v8
```

I can confirm this works with rbenv and ruby 1.9.3p448

Comment: Same for me - os x 10.9, rbenv and ruby-2.0.0-p247

Comment: Worked on 1.8.7 for an old project :)

Comment: Works for me on 1.9.3 :)

Comment: Why does this work? Which part of the command is --with-system-v8 modifying, and what is it doing?

Comment: As per the instructions here https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8 libv8 allows you to use a pre-existing version of the V8 engine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) rather than compiling one yourself. It's the compilation that is an issue in mavericks as the C++ compilers have changed. You can compile libV8 yourself using the instructions here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19668162/2012130)

Comment: works with rbenv and ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784)

Comment: works with rbenv and ruby 2.1.1 - `gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8`

Comment: Confirmed for rvm, ruby 2.1.4, and libv8 3.16.14.3

Comment: Works for high sierra too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to resolve this problem half of day
This install helped me resolve this problem

Answer (score 35):

El Capitan Solution for me:

```
$ brew install v8
$ gem install libv8 -v REQUIRED_LIBV8_VERSION -- --with-system-v8
```

Where `REQUIRED_LIBV8_VERSION` for me was `3.16.14.7`, but you need to check which is the one you need in your bundle (this was the one for rails `4.2.5`)

You may also need to run the commands above as the superuser (if your gems and system libraries are global)

Comment: You shouldn't use sudo for brew install or gem install. This creates permission issues.

Comment: @benDangelo, what you say is absolutely correct. Even though the system sometimes might require root privileges for installing software it's a bad practice to use sudo on a general basis. I'll edit my response, thanks.

Comment: It works for me! thank you. This was the only working solution.

Comment: just installing v8 did the work for me ... then no need to add flags with gem command

Answer (score 21):

You can configure bundler instead of having to know each version. @3.15 could be replaced with other versions.

```
$ brew install v8@3.15
$ bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8
$ bundle config build.therubyracer --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8@3.15)
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Works on macOS Catalina. Thank you!

Comment: You're my saviour, I have pretty old application with rubyracer dependency. The only note, brew don't have other v8 versions now, just `v8@3.15` and `v8`

Comment: Worked for me on Monterey. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

My issue is since `therubyracer`, when update to `macOS 10.15` and `ruby-2.6.5`

And the following works for me:

```
brew install v8@3.15

gem install libv8 -v 3.16.14.19 -- --with-system-v8

gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me to get therubyracer working on an old project on Catalina. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you., worked for me in Catalina, ruby 2.7.2, rails 5.2.4.

Answer (score 15):

When I tried the accepted answer, libv8 would install successfully with `gem install libv8`, but `bundle install` would fail on libv8. I think that `bundle install` was trying to install a different version of libv8. I was able to find a solution that worked for me.

I needed libv8 because therubyracer depends on it. To get it to install, I noted the version that was failing to install in the `gem_make.out` log for therubyracer. (The path for the `gem_make.out` log will be in the failure message.) In my case it was 3.16.14.7. (This version will probably change over time, in case you're reading this three years from now.) Then I did this:

`gem install libv8 -v 3.16.14.7 -- --with-v8-lib` <-- note different flag from accepted answer

which allowed this to work:

`gem install therubyracer`

which allowed me to complete my `bundle install`.

This worked for me on OSX Yosemite.

Comment: I should note that bundle install broke for me immediately after I upgraded to OSX Yosemite, which is why I had to find this solution.

Comment: This works brilliantly on OS X Yosemite while many other answers simply do not work.

Comment: Thanks mate. 'therubyracer' finally installed.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/339

jasonlynes's solution found on that link made the trick for me. anything else didn't work.

```
brew install homebrew/versions/v8-315
brew link --overwrite v8-315 --force
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.13' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2' -- --with-system-v8
```

Comment: I can't believe why this is still an issue in 2020... Thanks @Stefanos.Ioannou this is the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I updated to **macOS Catalina @ 10.15** and **`ruby 2.6.5`**. After a while got `libv8` and `therubyracer` to install again, although I'd recommend not to update macOS yet (I heard `ruby` should be fine).

First, I had to update XCode

1. `xcode-select --install`

I used `rbenv` to update `ruby`, and set the `ruby` version manually in `/Users/<username>/.rbenv/version` to `2.6.5`. Although this shouldn't matter if your project contains a `.ruby-version` file.

Then I cleaned up any version I installed fro `libv8` (usually in `/usr/local/opt/`): `brew uninstall v8`, `brew uninstall libv8@3.15`

2. `brew install v8@3.15`

Now, following https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8#do-i-get-a-binary, I installed

3. `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' -- --with-system-v8`

and then could run `bundle install` without errors.

Answer (score 5):

None of this helped me... no matter what I did, my gem install of therubyracer kept complaining with this error:

```
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Beginning compilation. This will take some time.
Building v8 with env CXX=clang++ LINK=clang++  /usr/local/bin/gmake x64.release ARFLAGS.target=crs werror=no
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
              -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
              -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
              -S.x64 -Dmac_deployment_target=10.15 -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3 -Dwerror=''
  File "build/gyp/gyp", line 12
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gmake: *** [Makefile:268: out/Makefile.x64] Error 1
```

What ultimately helped me was this other forum I stumbled upon at https://www.bountysource.com/issues/82833405-libv8-fails-to-build-on-catalina-10-15

The final solution that worked for me:

I had to add these lines to my .zshrc file:

```
export CXX=clang++
export GYPFLAGS=-Dmac_deployment_target=10.15
```

Then I had to run these commands:

```
source ~/.zshrc
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-core
brew install v8@3.15
gem uninstall therubyracer
gem uninstall libv8
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
bundle install
```

I hope someone else finds this useful!

Answer (score 3):

Try with what I summarized in this question: ["gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.2'" on osx mavericks not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630154/gem-install-therubyracer-v-0-10-2-on-osx-mavericks-not-installing/19762877)

It worked for me (OS X Mavericks)

Answer (score 1):

**This worked fine for me:**

Try installing this pre-compiled gem:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7919548/gems/libv8/libv8-3.11.8.17-x86_64-darwin-13.gem 
  (sha1:5ce07aaf4085fff5a5e10fe018fd6b22021bef3b)

Or if you prefer to build your own:

```
  git clone https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8.git
  cd libv8
  git checkout 3.11
  bundle install
  bundle exec rake clean build binary
  gem install pkg/libv8-3.11.8.17-x86_64-darwin-13.gem
```

Source: https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/107

Thanks to [Felix Bünemann](https://github.com/felixbuenemann) for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I upgraded from OSX Mountain Lion to OSX Mavericks.
The accepted answer worked for libv8, but not when I went to bundle install therubyracer gem.

Upgrading from ruby-1.8.7-p354 to ruby-1.8.7-375 did the trick for me.
libv8 (3.16.14.3-x86_64-darwin-13) and the therubyracer (0.12.0) gems installed without problem.

assuming you use rbenv:

```
rbenv versions
  system
  * 1.8.7-p354
  2.0.0-rc2

rbenv uninstall 1.8.7-p354
rbenv install 1.8.7-p375

rbenv versions
  system
  * 1.8.7-p375
  2.0.0-rc2

bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a number of solutions outlined in previous answers, but found that running bundle (to install other, missing gems) would attempt to re-compile libv8 (despite having already installed it successfully using `--with-system-v8`) and thus suffer from the same issue.

Eventually, I found that removing the libv8 gem, fetching the gem file from rubygems, and then manually installing the `.gem` file with the `--with-system-v8` flag worked for me.

i.e.

```
gem uninstall libv8
gem fetch libv8 -v LIBV8_VERSION
gem install libv8-LIBV_VERSION.gem -- --with-system-v8
bundle
```

Thanks to 
[Gaurav Agarwal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19586282/2737435) for leading me down the right path!

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually compiling and installing the gem via the method mentioned on [the libv8 github site.](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/107)

Answer (score 0):

In MAC-Yosemite with RVM environment and ruby-2.1.1 version

`gem install libv8 -v 3.16.14.3 -- --with-v8-lib
gem install therubyracer`

It works with the help of above command, can confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

What really worked for me was upgrading ruby to 2.2.0, removing Gemfile.lock and bundling over again.

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

replace `3.16.14.7` with your version.

```
bundle install
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7' -- --with-system-v8

bundle install
gem uninstall libv8 -v '3.16.14.7' -- --with-system-v8

brew install homebrew/dupes/apple-gcc42

export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2
export CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/g++-4.2
export CPP=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/cpp-4.2

bundle install
```

Comment: this forces an older gcc, which would be a band-aid at best and will definitely cause issues down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem on El Cap. Here's what I did.

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
```

And then,

```
export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2
export CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/g++-4.2
export CPP=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/cpp-4.2
```

Finally,

```
brew uninstall v8
gem install libv8 -v 3.11.8.17 -- --with-system-v8
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a beta version of Xcode for another project and had forgotten. Switch back with `xcode-select`. Something like:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

Answer (score -6):

Remove from Gemfile:

gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

Comment: This sort of defeats the entire purpose of this post.