# An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello on and existing project, I'm using the `libv8` library, now I changed the computer but when I try to run the `bundle install` command I get the following error:

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem daemons (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
# some output omitted
Using koala 1.7.0rc1
Using launchy 2.4.2
Using letter_opener 1.2.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141129-32009-1ao2h0k.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.6
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Using compiler: g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
../src/cached-powers.cc:136:18: error: unused variable 'kCachedPowersLength' [-Werror,-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int kCachedPowersLength = ARRAY_SIZE(kCachedPowers);
                 ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
    from /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
    from /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                  -S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3
  CXX(target) /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@blabloo/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/libv8-3.16.14.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any help please.

Comment: did you run `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` ?

Comment: yes and I get the same error :(

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577759/installing-libv8-gem-on-mavericks