# Can not install gem therubyracer in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems

I am using Mac and I want to run Ruby On Rails project on docker.
My setup is:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y libv8-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libxslt-dev liblzma-dev patch git-core zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev nodejs yarn
RUN gem install bundler
RUN gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby
RUN gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --no-deployment
ADD . $APP_HOME
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5440:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bin/rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3007:3000"
    links:
      - db
```

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem "excon", "~> 0.79.0"
gem "activeadmin"
gem "devise"
gem "cancancan"
gem "haml-rails", "~> 2.0"
gem 'simple_token_authentication', '~> 1.0' # see semver.org
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-client-cli'
gem 'whenever'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-doc'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

I try run `docker build .`, but I always receive errors

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
./siteconf20210323-5-xzbchb.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Applying
/usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-building-tests.patch
Applying
/usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-werror-on-osx.patch
Applying
/usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-xcode-debugging.patch
Applying
/usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-imply-vfp3-and-armv7.patch
Applying
/usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-use-MAP_NORESERVE-on-freebsd.patch
Applying /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-use-vfp2.patch
Applying /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/fPIC-for-static.patch
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.16
Using compiler: c++ (GCC version 8.3.0)
Beginning compilation. This will take some time.
Building v8 with env CXX=c++ LINK=c++  /usr/bin/make x64.release
ARFLAGS.target=crs werror=no
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
              -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
              -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
-S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1
-Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2
-Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3 -Dwerror=''
make[1]: Entering directory


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/libv8-3.16.14.19/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.19), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  therubyracer was resolved to 0.12.3, which depends on
    libv8
```

So please help me.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577759/installing-libv8-gem-on-os-x-10-9?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing libv8 gem on OS X 10.9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577759/installing-libv8-gem-on-os-x-10-9)

Comment: It will install directly on Mac OS, but I install rubytracer in docker container.

Comment: It works for me (I omitted `Gemfile.lock` since I didn't `bundle install` on the host). I'm on an Intel Mac. Are you on Intel or Apple Silicon?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with a cached build layer? You could try `docker build --no-cache .`

Comment: @DavidArndt I use two other mac but both use intel mac, with mac 2015 it can not run and raise error as above, but with mac 2018 it work well.

Comment: Maybe you should post your `Gemfile.lock`. Is it the same `Gemfile.lock` every time? Anyway, my best guess is that you are using cached build layers on one Mac and not the other.